# How to Display Data from and input textbox without using a button at all

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am building a page for the use of Law enforcement. The page will be for logging the charges of a suspect. The idea is that they type the charges into a text-box,(which has in-build auto completing and allows for multiple values). I then want to have the data passed to the next part of the same page which will take each charge and add them up the total ticket amount/ jail-time. I want the data to be passed as the user is typing or maybe as the text-box is deselected(out of focus).

and then if possible have all of the charges (which are already separated by commas) put into a table each in a different row.

I understand this is a big ask but if someone can point me in the right direction that would be great!

This is the Current testing HTML:

```
    <body>
<div id="wrapper">

<div class="ui-widget">
 <p>Enter Charges</p>
 <input type="text" id="charges">
</div>
</div>
```

and this is my scripts:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    function split( val ) {
        return val.split( /,\s*/ );
    }
    function extractLast( term ) {
        return split( term ).pop();
    }

    $( "#charges" ).bind( "keydown", function( event ) {
        if ( event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
            $( this ).autocomplete( "instance" ).menu.active ) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    })
    .autocomplete({
        minLength: 1,
        source: function( request, response ) {
            // delegate back to autocomplete, but extract the last term
            $.getJSON("autocomplete.php", { term : extractLast( request.term )},response);
        },
        focus: function() {
            // prevent value inserted on focus
            return false;
        },
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            var terms = split( this.value );
            // remove the current input
            terms.pop();
            // add the selected item
            terms.push( ui.item.value );
            // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
            terms.push( "" );
            this.value = terms.join( ", " );
            return false;
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

it also uses a php file to run through my database to get all charges.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: http://jsfiddle.net/MyZgX/ this jsfiddle is using my exact code and works fine but doesn't work on my personal page I have my jquery and jquery UI libraries loaded too..

Comment: Have you looked at using something like Angular?

Comment: I have never used or seen angular so it really didn't cross my mind :D

Comment: Angular let's you bind your input field to a variable and then use that variable elsewhere and it will dynamically update. [Brief Intro](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/databinding)